# ApplicationReadyEvent not listened to when declaring @ComponentScan for library package

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
@componentscan({"com.test.cloud"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(TestClass.class, args);
}
}

public class TestClass2{

@eventlistener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void testMethod() {
.....
.....
}
}
```

Here if I remove @componentscan({"com.test.cloud"}) annotation then the testMethod is triggered. But when I use @componentscan({"com.test.cloud"}) then the testMethod is not triggered.

SpringBoot Version: 1.5.10.RELEASE

Comment: What is your project structure? In which package the `TestClass` resides?

Comment: TestClass and TestClass2 reside in the same base package. for example com.example.demo but com.test.cloud is the external library added by dependency.

Comment: The `@ComponentScan` overrides the other package, you need to add both packages to the scan **or** define a top level package like `com.test`.

Comment: So you should have something like `@componentscan({"com.test.cloud","com.example.demo"})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked by adding:

@componentscan({"com.test.cloud","com.example.demo"})